# PHP Calculating GPA and user-defined functions

Tags: php

http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~tboegel/semesterGPA1.php

My form supposed to calculate the GPA of the courses (link above). I still need to calculate total points, GPA, Quality total. I think I can figure it out myself, but I need to find out how to $_REQUEST['course1'], course2, course3, units1, units2, etc... (see below)

So far, I have

```
<?php
$course = $_REQUEST['course0'];
$units = $_REQUEST['units0'];
$letterGrade = $_REQUEST['letterGrade0'];
$letterGrade = strtoupper($letterGrade);
if($letterGrade == 'A') {
    $numberGrade = 4;
} elseif ($letterGrade == 'B') {
    $numberGrade = 3;                                                                           
} elseif ($letterGrade == 'C')  {
    $numberGrade = 2;                                                                           
} elseif ($letterGrade == 'D')  {
    $numberGrade = 1;                                                                           
} else {
    $numberGrade = 0;                                                                           
}

$qualityPoints = $units * $numberGrade;

function calculateQualityPoints($course, $units, $letterGrade, $qualityPoints) {
echo "<tr><td>$course</td><td>$units</td><td>$letterGrade</td><td>$qualityPoints</td></tr>";

}

echo "<table width='50%' align='left'><tr><th>Course</th><th>Units</th><th>Letter Grade</th><th>Quality Points</th></tr>";
calculateQualityPoints($course, $units, $letterGrade, $qualityPoints);                          
echo "<tr><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>total</strong></td><td></td><td><strong>quality total</strong></td></tr><tr><td><strong>GPA</strong></td><td><strong>GPA #</strong></td></tr></table>";                                                                                    

?>
```

Only the first text box works. How do I grab course1, course2, course3, units1, units2, letterGrade1, etc?

This code is from the HTML form to input the courses, grade, and units.

```
<?php
  for ($i=0; $i<5; $i+=1) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "\t<td><input type='text' name='course$i'></td>\n";
    print "\t<td><input type='text' name='units$i' size=5></td>\n";
    print "\t<td><input type='text' name='letterGrade$i' size=5></td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You can have `name="course[]"`, and `$_REQUEST['course']` will be an array, afaicr..

Answer (score 1):

Your using the post method in your form, so in semesterGPA2.php, you should use $POST['name'] to access those input variables, where name is Course 0, 1, 2, etc. You can use another for loop to display this.

Your code should look something like this, hope it helps. Don't guarantee there are no typos!.

```
<?php
//maybe put the th tag here, course, units lettergrade, etc.
$qualityPoints = 0;
$units = 0;
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {

    //these are just the names in input name = "", can rename yo anything you want
    $courseName = 'course'.$i; 
    $unitsName = 'units'.$i;
    $letterGradeName = 'lettergrade'.$i;

    //we are using post to retrieve these form input variables
    $letterGrade = $POST[$letterGradename];
    $units = $POST[$unitsName];
    $course = $POST[$courseName];
    //calculate the quality points for each one
    $qualityPoints = calculateQualityPoints($units, $letterGrade);
    //maybe hereyou can just output(echo) each row with the above information
    //echo above info

    //you can aggregate them here for output of the final grade, like a report card
    $qualityPoints += $qualityPoints;
    $units += $units;
}

//here you can use the total quality points and the total units to calculate gpa
$GPA = ($qualityPoints/$units)/25;
echo "GPA:". $GPA;
//or even make a function to calculate GPA
//Why not even create a report card class that encapsulates all of this, but may be over kill!
function calculateQualityPoints($units, $letterGrade) {
    if($letterGrade == 'A') {
        //you can conver the letter grade to number grade, or you can just do it directly 
        $qualityPoints = 100 * $units;
    } elseif ($letterGrade == 'B') {
        $qualityPoints = 75 * $units;                                                                         
    } elseif ($letterGrade == 'C')  {
        $qualityPoints = 50 * $units;                                                                        
    } elseif ($letterGrade == 'D')  {
        $qualityPoints = 25 * $units;                                                                           
    } else {
        $qualityPoints = 0;                                                                          
    }
    return $qualityPoints;
}

?>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the text fields can be left blank, so if I leave one text field blank. I think I get an error from using that loop

Comment: just add a check to see what the post value is, if black ''   or NULL, and reroute your code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

just do a check , if the value == '' or NULL

Answer (score 0):

Replace `calculateQualityPoints($course, $units, $letterGrade, $qualityPoints);`   with this ...It should work

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i+=1) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$_REQUEST['course'.$i]."</td><td>".$_REQUEST['units'.$i]."</td>";      
   echo "<td>$letterGrade</td><td>$qualityPoints</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: That seems like it could work. Thanks, but I need to use a user-defined function because my assignment requires I use a function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $ban1 = 50;
    $ban2 = -22;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Markssheet</title>
        <style>
            th {
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 12px;
                background-color: blueviolet;
                color: #fff;
            }
            td{
                padding: 8px;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><h2>Enter Your Data</h2></center>
            <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                   <th width="5%">SL NO.</th>
                   <th width="20%">Subject Name</th>
                   <th width="5%">Marks</th>
                   <th width="5%">L.G.</th>
                   <th width="5%">GP</th>
               </tr>
               <tr> <!--Bangla First Paper-->
                   <td>01</td>
                   <td>Bangla First Paper</td>
                   <td><?php echo $ban1 ?></td>
                   <td>
                       <?php
                          if(101 > $ban1 | $ban1 > 79){echo 'A+';}   
                          elseif(80 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 69){echo 'A';}   
                          elseif(70 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 59){echo 'A-';}  
                          elseif(60 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 49){echo 'B';}   
                          elseif(50 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 39){echo 'C';}   
                          elseif(40 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 32){echo 'D';}
                          elseif(33 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 0){echo 'F';}
                          else{ echo "Unalocated Number";} 
                       ?>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <?php
                          if(101 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 79){echo '5.00';}   
                          elseif(80 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 69){echo '4.00';}   
                          elseif(70 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 59){echo '3.50';}   
                          elseif(60 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 49){echo '3.00';}   
                          elseif(50 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 39){echo '2.00';}   
                          elseif(40 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 32){echo '1.00';}   
                          elseif(33 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 0){echo '0.00';}
                          else{ echo "Unalocated Number";} 
                       ?>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr> <!--Bangla Secound Paper-->
                   <td>02</td>
                   <td>Bangla Secound Paper</td>
                   <td><?php echo $ban2 ?></td>
                   <td>
                       <?php
                          if(101 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 79){echo 'A+';}  
                          else if(80 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 69){echo 'A';}   
                          else if(70 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 59){echo 'A-';}   
                          else if(60 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 49){echo 'B';}   
                          else if(50 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 39){echo 'C';}   
                          else if(40 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 32){echo 'D';}   
                          else if(33 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 0){echo 'F';}
                          else{ echo "Unalocated Number";} 
                       ?>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <?php
                          if(101 > $ban1 || $ban1 > 79){echo '5.00';}   
                          else if(80 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 69){echo '4.00';}   
                          else if(70 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 59){echo '3.50';}   
                          else if(60 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 49){echo '3.00';}   
                          else if(50 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 39){echo '2.00';}   
                          else if(40 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 32){echo '1.00';}   
                          else if(33 > $ban2 || $ban2 > 0){echo '0.00';}
                          else{ echo "Unalocated Number";} 
                       ?>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```